# ARCGIS API 4 -- Custom marker images for each point or address

Tags: arcgis-js-api

There are several examples in the API, but for some reason, what I think the biggest feature is eluding me for some reason. I have a list of points and each point needs to be represented by a different icon. I also may have layers that use the same icon which I can find, just not the option for different icons/markers. An example of this would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to use the Graphic option to add an array of points that have a different url for their markers (symbols). This used the Picture Marker type. The beauty of JSON!!